# Failed to construct 'AudioBuffer'. invalid audio data in ArrayBuffer

Tags: html, web-audio-api

I get below error only for a particular mp3 file. File plays well in `<audio>` control.

> Failed to construct 'AudioBuffer': invalid audio data in ArrayBuffer.

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to host the file somewhere so I can take a look.

Comment: Hmm, weird.  It seems like it's just corrupted somewhere; if you load the file in Audacity and re-save it in MP3, it works fine.

Comment: thanks! It works after I re-save from Audacity. Might be some issue with file.